# Ubuntu Server 14 connects on LAN but not WAN

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan

Every time I boot my newly installed Ubuntu 14.0.4, it always says "Waiting for network configuration". When I log in, I have to type `sudo ifconfig enp3s8 up` to activate my adapter (for some reason it is always enp3s8, eth0 doesn't exist on my machine). Then, `sudo ifconfig enp3s8 inet 192.168.0.14` to give it the address. I can ping devices on LAN, but anything WAN related fails.

Any ideas? I have searched and searched but to no avail :(

Thanks, Josh.